# NullPointerException when using setImageBitmap in onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` when using `setImageBitmap`

**"result"** is a valid bitmap.

Here is my code:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);            
    try {

        ImageView imageView1;
        imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgbanner);
        imageView1.setImageBitmap(result);

        return;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logMensajes("Error imageload onPostExecute: "+e.toString());
    }
}
```

XML

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgbanner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitulo"/>
```

Comment: show us how you get `result`.

Comment: is onPostExecute in avtivity form ?

Comment: Tip: You probably shouldn't be using `findViewById` from within the AsyncTask. Secondly, please show a [mcve] of all the necessary code to get to this `onPostExecute`

Comment: try adding `runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){ //your code });` withing your async response

Comment: as should call findViewById within a AsyncTask?

Answer (score 0):

Make the `ImageView` Activity scoped instead of within your async task:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    ImageView mImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.your_view_xml);
         mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgbanner);
    }


    class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Bitmap>{

       @Override
       protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void ...){
            //....
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);   
           if(result != null){
             mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
           }          
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I supposed thats is a Async task, so... in the doInBackground you must do somenthing like:

```
protected void doInBackground(String... params) {
        .
        .
        .
        //your code
        Bitmap image = something;

        return image;
     }
```

Ensure that "image" is set a value